# How to expand a table row in only one direction?

Tags: html, css, html-table, row, overflow

Following problem: I want the table row to only flow in down-direction. But I want to still have the label in the first cell vertical fitting to the EditTextBox I have in between.

[image: Tables]

I tried to put the label and the EditTextBox in a DIV and put them in vertical-align:middle; but it didn't work.

I would be very happy if someone could give me some help with this. I am sure this is not a big issue but I didn't get it yet.

Comment: Can u provide me ur jsfiddle link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You give it an absolute position

eg

```
td input {
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
}
```

This will ensure it expands downwards. The `top:5px;` is how far from the top you want the input element

Comment: Thank you! This works fine but there is still a problem;
The whole tr should expand downwards, otherwise there will be a problem with following rows.
http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/3329/zhj5fmux_png.htm

Comment: you might need to tweak it to suit your setup, but this is the logic.